# How to print date in perl?

Tags: perl, date

I am printing today's date in cgi-perl using the following code:

```
 my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = 
              localtime(time);
              $year = $year + 1900;
              $mon++;

              print "$mday/$mon/$year\n";
```

I need to print exactly the date exactly 7 days(1 week) before the current date.

Answer (score 4):

```
use DateTime qw( );

my $dt = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' );
$dt->subtract( days => 7 );
say $dt->strftime("%d/%m/%Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one-liner print statement to print localtime in perl is:

```
print scalar localtime (); #Output: Fri Nov 22 14:25:58 2019
```

Hope this helps!